# Convert PFX to PEM and error "unable to load certificate"

Tags: ssl, openssl, amazon-cloudfront, pem, pfx

I am trying to converted a wildcard SSL certificate to PEM format so I can use it in Amazon's Cloudfront. The only file format I have available is pfx. I tried using the following commands:

**Extract the private key from the PFX**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in {site}.pfx  -nocerts -nodes -passin pass:{password} | openssl rsa -out {site}.key
```

**Extract the public key from the PFX**

```
openssl pkcs12 –in {site}.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -passin pass:{password} | openssl x509 -out {site}.cer
```

**Extract the chain bundle from the PFX**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in {site}.pfx -nodes -nokeys -cacerts -passin pass:{password} | openssl x509 -out bundle.crt
```

The first two commands ran without any problems, however the last one is returning the following:

```
MAC verified OK
unable to load certificate
17856:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should get that error if (and only if) the PFX contains *just* the server cert and *no* CA cert(s). Do `openssl pkcs12 -in whatever.pfx -nokeys` and see how many BEGIN CERTIFICATE/END CERTIFICATE block(s) are displayed and the names (subject and issuer) for each. PS: `-nodes` is useless and ignored with `-nokeys`; if/when there is more than one CA cert, piping through `openssl x509` discards all but the first giving a probably useless result.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

With the `pkcs12` context in `openssl` you can specify what components you want from the pfx file. If you don't want the signed certificate but just issuer certificates, try this:

`openssl pkcs12 -in mycerts.pfx -cacerts -out myissuercerts.cer`

To get the crt file extension just rename the file from .cer to .crt.
http://www.networksolutions.com/support/what-is-the-difference-between-a-crt-and-a-cer-file/

Hope this helps.